# Pandas how to calculate sum for columns in list x and mean for columns in list y using aggregate

Tags: pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe with 60+ columns.  I want to calculate **sum for the column names starting with 'FLAG_'** and **mean for the column names starting with 'RESPONSE_'** . How to achieve this? I tried using **agg()** with no luck.

**Note:** I'm trying to achieve this as part of **data pipeline**

```
sum_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'FLAG_' in col]
mean_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'RESPONSE_' in col]
dict_ = {tuple(sum_cols): 'sum', tuple(mean_cols): 'mean'}
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(dict_)
```

but I'm getting error because while selecting the columns it should be a list rather tuple. since it's a dictionary I cannot pass list as key.

```
KeyError: "Column(s) [array([#<All the FLAG_ columns listed>], dtype=object)] do not exist"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    sum_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'FLAG_' in col]
    mean_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'RESPONSE_' in col]
    dict_ = {col:'sum' for col in sum_cols}
    dict_.update({col:'mean' for col in mean_cols})
    df = df.groupby('ID').agg(dict_)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?